# Detect video ID with regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to detect the 9 digit ID part of the vimeo's URL. Here is what I have so far.

```
/\[\[(https?:\/\/vimeo\.com\/[0-9]+$)\]\]/gm

[[https://vimeo.com/channels/mercedesbenz/166551756]]
[[https://vimeo.com/153002910]]
[[https://vimeo.com/jp/channels/staffpicks/259634725]]
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Why not just match all digits before `]]`? [`[0-9]+(?=]])`](https://regex101.com/r/xgOvax/1).

Comment: `.*\/(\d{9})(?:[]])` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for end of input while there are two characters left and you are looking for digits immediately after domain name while in your sample inputs they come in different orders within URL.

```
\[\[(https?:\/\/vimeo\.com\/[0-9]+$)\]\]
                            ^^^^^^^
```

You could do this:

```
\[\[https?:\/\/vimeo\.com\/[^\]]*?(\d+)\]\]
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bEtJcK/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

[`(?<=\/)\d{9}(?=]]$)`](https://regex101.com/r/CGcTJB/1)

This will match 9 digits when they appear after a slash `/` and before `]]$` where `$` represents the end of the line. To match only vimeo links you could include `vimeo.*` in the previous regex, and capture the digits in group 1:

`vimeo.*(?<=\/)(\d{9})(?=]]$)`